# dd-wrt freeradius validation

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, freeradius

I have a Linksys router with Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (11/02/09) vpn-small.
The objetive is have a way to ask for user and password when connecting to the WiFi dd-wrt AP, and depending on the user entered, allow full (for employees) access or guests.
We will be using an external freeradius server running on Ubuntu 14 (server).
I have searched over the web and found many pages that prompt to edit, configure or setup any number of freeradius (and other) files without clearly explaining why. I have many questions but I guess is not polite to ask more than one per entry so my main question is:
**What is the difference between a freeradius user and a freeradius client?**
All I know for sure(?) is that users are stored in *etc/freeradius/users* and clients in */etc/freeradius/clients.conf*
I don´t want to dive in setting a mysql database for freeradius until I understand such difference
Any clear freeradius tutorial will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RADIUS 'client' is the device which sends RADIUS requests on behalf of the connecting users.

In other words, for WPA-Enterprise, **your Wi-Fi access point** needs to be listed in clients.conf.

(The Wi-Fi or 802.1X user devices speak EAP inside some *other* encapsulation, but it's the AP which converts that to RADIUS packets.)

Comment: That certainly explains more than many pages. Thank you